# How can I capture a field name (not field value) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out how I can use javascript to capture the name of a field and assign the name to a variable. I've done a good amount of searching, but I can only find out how to capture the value of a field and not the name of the field itself.

For example, say I have a asp textbox named "ClientFName". I'd like to use javascript to capture the name of the textbox (ClientFName) and assign the name to a variable.

I'm moderately experienced with javascript but I haven't figured out a way to make this happen. Any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? The "name" attribute is a property of the DOM element.  If your JavaScript code has a reference to the DOM element it just accesses the "name".

Comment: Capture in response to what? It being the only field on the page? It being the field clicked on? Something else?

Comment: I apologize for not providing enough detail. I'm looking to assign the field name to a variable when the onFocus event occurs.

My code does not currently have a reference to the DOM element, that would explain why I wasn't able to see the name property. I'll admit I feel a little silly now, and I need to revisit my solution. thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `getAttribute()` method you can get the attribute value, just check this:

```
<script> 
function check(){
var v= document.getElementById('mytext').getAttribute('name');
alert(v);
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="mytext" value="test" name="mytext1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  onclick="check();"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to find the element in the DOM (which I assume you can do since you can get the value).  Then use `.name` to access its name property, which you can then assign to a variable.

```
var myName = document.getElementById("myTextbox").name;
```